# Django: sorl-thumbnail and easy-thumbnail in same project

Tags: django, image, templates, thumbnails, sorl-thumbnail

I'm working on and project that uses two separate modular Django apps.  However, one app requires easy-thumbnails and the other requires sorl-thumbnails.  Unfortunately, the two thumbnail libraries make use of the template tag syntax {% load thumbnail %}, so they clash and break when a template using them tries to render.

Are there any approaches to solve this type of clash?  (For example, a template option does to the effect of {% load thumbnail as easy_thumbnail %}).  Am I going to have to fork one of the apps and replace one of the thumbnail libraries with another?  If so, which should I choose to go with?

Thank you for considering my question,
Joe

Comment: you should give https://github.com/codysoyland/django-smart-load-tag a try :)

Comment: That's a really neat module that seems like it will solve exactly this problem.  I think I saw a django ticket to add similar functionality to django trunk.  I hope it makes it in.  Nice that this module exists for current and past instances of django.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Django 1.9, you can use the `libraries` option of `DjangoTemplates` to include a tag library under a specified name. In the example below, the thumbnail library from `sorl.thumbnail` is included under the name `sorl_thumbnail`.

> **Note:** the templatetag itself is not changed within the template... *ie. remains `thumbnail`*

### Usage:

#### `settings.py`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "foo", "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'libraries': {
                'sorl_thumbnail': 'sorl.thumbnail.templatetags.thumbnail',
            },
        },
    },
]
```

#### `your_template.html`

```
{% load sorl_thumbnail %}
{% thumbnail mymodel.image "640x480" crop="center" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{im.width}}" height="{{im.height}}"/>
{% endthumbnail %}
```

Comment: Wow, this is awesome and a much needed feature !

Comment: is there a solution if you have two different third party apps, and both do a {% load thumbnail %}?

Answer (score 11):

Sure, just write your own stub easy_thumbnail wrapper...

1. Create a `thumbnailtags` package in one of your django apps...
2. ...making sure it's got an empty `__init__.py`
3. In `thumbnailtags/easy_thumbnail.py` do something like:

   ```
   from django.template import Library
   from easy_thumbnails.templatetags import thumbnail

   register = Library()    

   def easy_thumbnail(parser, token):
       return thumbnail(parser, token)

   register.tag(easy_thumbnail)
   ```
4. Use `{% load easy_thumbnail %}`

**Note:**

You might also be able to do 'import thumbnail as easy_thumbnail, and skip the `def easy_thumbnail` bit, tho I've not tried that.

Answer (score 6):

This blog link shows how to handle this.

https://timmyomahony.com/blog/using-sorl-thumbnail-and-easy-thumbnails-same-template/

(previously 
http://timmyomahony.com/blog/2012/10/22/using-sorl-thumbnail-and-easy-thumbnails-same-template/)

Comment: corrected response to show new url - https://timmyomahony.com/blog/using-sorl-thumbnail-and-easy-thumbnails-same-template/

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE 2015**

I had to do the following modifications to Tom Christie's answer in order to get this to work:

1. create a `templatetags` package in one of you local apps. It is important to name it `templatetags`. See [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/) for template tags.
2. ... make sure it has an `__init__.py`, empty or not.
3. In `templatetags/easy_thumbnail.py` do this:

   ```
   from django.template import Library
   from easy_thumbnails.templatetags import thumbnail

   register = Library()    

   def easy_thumbnail(parser, token):
       return thumbnail.thumbnail(parser, token) # the important bit

   register.tag(easy_thumbnail)
   ```
4. Use `{% load easy_thumbnail %}` or `- load easy_thumbnail` with [pyjade](https://github.com/SyrusAkbary/pyjade)